# $l_p$ integral with negative $p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let us take $0<p<1$ and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $X$. Let $L(f)=\sum_{x\in X} f(x)^{-p}\mu(x)$, for $f\in S:=\{f: f\ge 0, \sum_x f(x)=1\}$ (we are interested only in this region). I am wondering whether the balls $\{f\in S:F(f)\le \lambda\}$ are convex.

In the simplest case where $X=\{x_1,x_2\}$, $\mu(x_i)=1/2$, and $f=(1-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, $L(f)=2^p$ when $\epsilon=1/2$ and $L(f)\to \infty$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ or $\epsilon\to 1$. So it gives me a feeling that the level sets are convex. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $X$ a discrete space? If not so: What do you mean by $\mu(x)$ for a probability measure $\mu$?

Comment: @saz: Yes, in fact can assume $X$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that the function $\rho(t)=t^{-p}$ is convex on $[0,+\infty]$. As a result, the map $L: S\to [0,+\infty]$ is also convex. The conclusion follows.